# npm ERESOLVE error when installing Material UI

Tags: npm

Getting `ERESOLVE` error when trying to install `@material-ui/core` and `gatsby-plugin-material-ui`:

```sh
    npm install @material-ui/core gatsby-plugin-material-ui

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: gatsby-starter-default@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: gatsby@4.1.2
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby
npm ERR!   gatsby@"^4.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer gatsby@"^3.0.0" from gatsby-plugin-material-ui@4.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui
npm ERR!   gatsby-plugin-material-ui@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your dependency tree is either broken or the packages you are trying to install have dependencies on their own that are also used by other peer dependencies but on different versions.

First, try removing all installed packages and lock files:

```sh
rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json
```

You can then try re-installing them but with the `--legacy-peer-deps` flag:

```sh
npm install @material-ui/core gatsby-plugin-material-ui --legacy-peer-deps
```